# Friend methods in C++ is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, friend

I wrote the following code:

```
class Osoba{
private:
    string imie, nazwisko, kolorOczu;
    friend void Dziecko::coutall();
public:
    Osoba(string imie, string nazwisko, string kolorOczu):imie(imie), nazwisko(nazwisko), kolorOczu(kolorOczu){};
    void coutall(){
        cout << "Imie: " << imie << endl; //
        cout << "Nazwisko: " << nazwisko << endl;
        cout << "Kolor oczu: " << kolorOczu << endl;
    }

};

class Dziecko: public Osoba{
private:
    string nazwaPrzedszkola, choroba;
    typedef Osoba super;
public:
    Dziecko(string imie, string nazwisko, string kolorOczu, string nazwaPrzedszkola, string choroba):super(imie, nazwisko, kolorOczu), nazwaPrzedszkola(nazwaPrzedszkola), choroba(choroba){};
    void coutall(){
        cout << super::imie; // this one gets underlined.
        cout << "Nazwa przedszkola: " << nazwaPrzedszkola << endl;
        cout << "Choroba: " << choroba << endl;
    }
};
```

and this line is underlined:

```
cout << super::imie;
```

It says it's inaccessible. But in my opinion it is - I "friended" this method.
I tried a forward declaration of class Dziecko - didn't work, either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't call that method because it uses private members of class `Osoba`.

Try using the `imie` as a protected variable instead of private.

Here is a short [explenation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr130.htm).

The 2 options available are:

1) `friend` the entire class, not a good practice when using inheritance.

2) Use protected members. this is the best way to access private members on inheritance.

Comment: OP expects the `friend` declaration to fix this. So the question is, why doesn't it?

Comment: The page states `Private members of the base class cannot be used by the derived class unless friend declarations within the base class explicitly grant access to them`, which is the issue the OP seems to be encountering.

Comment: so you say I should friend the whole class? so it's impossible to friend just one method of a derived class?

Comment: @TomDavies92, the previous comments were right. im not on my pc right now so i cant check that. i would try to use the 'imie' as protected. for now. will that work?

Comment: @TomDavies92 the problem is that you need the full derived class definition in order to declare the friend member function. But you can't have it because it requires the full base definition. If there was no inheritance, you could make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it, because Dziecko::coutall is not defined when Osoba is compiled and there are no means in c++ to make forward member method declaration. Instead you can make friend all Dziecko class (as Nbr44 suggested)

Comment: This is correct. but making friend to the entire class doesnt look like the best practice if using inheritance...

Comment: I agree. Maybe it makes sense to provide protected method in Osoba that return const ref to imie?