# Restrict visibility of friend classes in C++

Tags: c++, friend

I want to allow a private method defined in class A to call a private method defined in class B.  I cannot declare a single friend method because class B's definition is already known by A (A already uses B), and including A's header in B would go circular.  Nor can I simply use a forward declaration, as explained here:

[MSDN: Friend declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/172fs28y.aspx)

I'm currently declaring A as a private friend of B, which exposes everything in B and is less desirable.  The article above has an intriguing teaser at the end:

"Although the entire second class must be a friend to the first class, you can select which functions in the first class will be friends of the second class."

I can't find a way to do this - is it possible?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954195/friend-methods-in-c-is-not-working/20954667#20954667

Comment: @pdm2011 here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e293c545fc421a64